# WatchKit: Create ring graph (One ring)

Tags: swift3, watchkit

I want to create circle graph on first page of Page Controller and bar graphic on second page of Page Controller. I have use WKInterfaceActivityRing, but it represent only 3 rings together.

I have 2 questions about WatchKit:

1. How to create standard ring graph (one ring)?
2. How to create standard bar graph?

What i mean:

[image]

p.s. Sorry for my English

Answer (score 1):

I have created a bar graph similar to the one listed by simply adding groups side by side within a containing group and setting all of their widths to say 5 pixels, and the height to zero. Set the height of the container group to say 100 pixels. Then create an outlet for each "element" group within the container and assign the height of the group to be equal to whatever value you want to display. If your scale is only 1 - 10 then calculate what percentage of 10 your value is and multiply that by 100 to tell the element group how large to be.

for example

scale is 1 - 10, value is 5 which is 50%, or .5 of 10, 100 * .5 is 50 so set your element groups height to be 50

Hope that makes sense